# highcharts series update in javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating 5 separate charts and try to update them every few seconds with new series data.
If I define just one function that creates new chart and add series data in constructor, it works, but the downside is that every page refresh with setInterval() destroys charts and rebuilds them, which looks terrible.

So I created two functions, CreateChart() called once, and UpdateChart() called on every setInterval() refresh. Now charts are empty and I get error on UpdateChart():

> TypeError: FlightCharts[Index].series[0] is undefined

[Link to javascript code](http://pastebin.com/0qjv0RL7)
[Link to  example json series data](http://pastebin.com/VFY1mVB6)

Any tips (I'm new to javascript)

thanks

Comment: 1st tip: paste the codes in your question, instead of pastebin

Comment: Can you past your solution to jsfiddle or something other?

Comment: Ok, I put this on https://jsfiddle.net/czvLdqq5/2/ and simplified a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined empty series:

```
series: []
```

Next you are trying to set data for a first series:

```
FlightCharts[Index].series[0]
```

Instead you should create that one series at least:

```
series: [{
  name: "MyName",
  data: []
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Paweł. I did give it a try, but no success.
I think problem with my setup is that I have array of many series.
I put the code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/czvLdqq5/6/ and trying some options but none give me any results.
How do I update multi-series?

Comment: Just create multiple series in `seres: [ ... ]` array. So later you will not reference non existing series.

Comment: But what if number of series is changing? I need to add/remove array elements and that's where I'm stuck. It's not working for me.

thanks

Comment: Then use different approach. Currently you have `chart.series[index].setData()`. Check if `chart.series[index]` exists, and if not, use `chart.addSeries()` instead of `chart.series[index].setData()` to add new series.

Comment: Thanks Paweł
I was able to finaly fix this, code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/czvLdqq5/39/

Now I try to find out how to disable animation on updates (as this was a real cause I looked into series update without chart rebuild).
But I guess I'll open a new question.